# Keyboard Shortcut For 'Show Transform Controls' in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

Does anyone know if you can set up a key command to toggle Show Transform Controls off and on? Transforming with CMD + T off and on is the best solution that I know of, but it would be nice to have a way to toggle Show Transform Controls since my solution only applies to the layer you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, **no keyboard shortcut**.

Select the Move Tool and then check the Show Transform Controls option in the top toolbar:

[image]

If you want to *hide* the controls, you can quickly toggle hide/show all extras with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Hiding with ⌘ + H works perfectly. That's a great hack to know.